# how can I display mounted partitions in unity (ubuntu 12.10)

Tags: 12.10, unity, mount

I have a couple of mounted volumes ( under /media and ~/ ), but neither of which will ever display on my unity bar. I do however see both volumes listed in nautilus. What's interesting is that no partitions display on my unity launcher whatsoever (no iphone, disc, usb storage, etc.). I know you can also blacklist the UUID of a volume from displaying, but none of these items are blacklisted. How can I go about fixing this? Thanks!
 [image: nautilus]

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

1. Open up `CompizConfig Settings Manager` by running:

   `ccsm`

   You might have to install it first by running

   `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`
2. Once `ccsm` is running, open up `Ubuntu Unity Plugin`.
3. Under the `Experimental` tab, select `Always` for the `Show Devices` setting.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think this option was removed after 12.04 though :(

Comment: Oh right! I totally missed the version in your title! Sorry buddy.